# Как узнать цвет пикселя не используя canvas?

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

Есть такой код.

```
#photo{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
#wrapper{
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 1px;
    height: 1px;
}

<div id=wrapper>
    <img src="image.jpg" alt="" id="photo">
</div>
```

Как узнать цвет пикселя который видно?

Comment: цвет какого пикселя?

Comment: Классный вопрос, виден где? Под курсором мышки или вы имели ввиду определить усредненный цвет img. Исходя из кода wrapper зажат на 1px и вы хотите определить какой цвет пикселя попал в эту точку?

Comment: Какой цвет пикселя попал в эту точку.

Comment: Довольно таки странная затея.
Если без canvas, то вижу 2 пути.
1. Флэш. Смешно конечно, но всё-же вариант )
2. Можно заслать координаты точьки на сервер, а он вернёт цвет
Вот только не пойму, чем canvas не угодил )

Comment: вот это не то, что вы хотите ?  - https://ruseller.com/lessons.php?rub=1&id=1500

Comment: нет, там <canvas id="panel" width="500" height="333"></canvas>

Comment: Эм...... никак =)

Comment: Если картинки в пределах одного сервера, то почему бы не canvas без отображения даже. Если это конечно не домашнее задание типа "Сделать не используя канвас какими-нибудь деревянными методами"

Comment: @GOGANOID_, а чем canvas не угодил?

Comment: Вобще возможно получить - но не произвольного пикселя, а пикселя из картинки. Те просто скачать картинку и распарсить ее в javascript - canvas не нужен.

Comment: Можно использовать AJAX.
Отправляем картинку на сервер, а сервер находит пиксель, и возвращает его цвет.

Comment: @GOGANOID_, жду вашего отклика на мой ответ. Если он вас устраивает - просто поставьте галочку.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если canvas использовать нельзя, то единственным возможным решением будет использование AJAX для запроса на сервер. На сервере находится точно такая же картинка как и на клиенте, либо же картинка отправляется на него вместе с запросом. Сервер находит цвет пикселя по X и Y координатам из запроса, и возвращает его цвет в JSON-формате.

**Код PHP-сервера:**

```
<?php
    header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
    $x = $_GET["x"];
    $y = $_GET["y"];

    //Загрузка JPG-изображения из файла "image.jpg"
    $image = imagecreatefromjpeg("image.jpg");
    //Возвращаем цвет пикселя с координатами ($x, $y) на изображении $image
    $color = imagecolorat($image, $x, $y);
    //Получаем составляющие цвета (red, green, blue)
    $col = new stdClass();
    $col->r = ($color >> 16) & 0xFF;
    $col->g = ($color >> 8) & 0xFF;
    $col->b = $color & 0xFF;

    //Выводим JSON для AJAX-запрса:
    echo json_encode($col);

    //Освобождаем память сервера
    imageDestroy($image);
?>
```

**Код клиента:**

```
<html><body style="margin:0;padding:0">
<img src="image.jpg"><!-- картинка на сервере и клиенте одна -->
<br>
<div id="mouse-position"></div>
<div id="color"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
{
    if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200)
    {
        var color = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        document.getElementById('color').innerHTML = color.r + ', ' + color.g + ', ' + color.b;
    }
};

function sendAJAX(x, y)
{
    xmlhttp.open('GET', 'getColorRGB.php?x='+x+'&y='+y, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}

document.querySelector('img').onclick = function(e)
{
    document.getElementById('mouse-position').innerHTML = 'x = ' + e.pageX + ', y = ' + e.pageY;
    sendAJAX(e.pageX, e.pageY)
};
</script>
</body></html>
```

Обратите внимание на то, что здесь указано `<body style="margin:0;padding:0">` для того, чтобы картинка отображалась в верхнем левом углу без отступа. Это сделано для того, чтобы картинка совмещалась с координатами документа, ибо `e.pageX` и `e.pageY` отображают координаты документа. В общем здесь ещё необходимо правильно передавать координаты, если картинка будет смещена. Но для этого примера это излишне.

Comment: За ответ на этот вопрос 6 месяцев назад обещали [100 баллов репутации](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/737859/revisions). Никто их не получил. Сегодня я написал правильный ответ, но ответ уже никому не нужно?